# Magento 2: How to add a new phtml(template) to a layout file so I can use it in the head section?

Tags: magento2.3, layout, phtml, template-override

I am trying to add a phtml template file to the layout file so that I can use this template in the head section to insert contents from an JS file. Please tell me what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check below XML code

I have created a custom theme and create a default layout in the theme. I have added a template to head using below XML code.

```
<referenceContainer name="head.additional">
            <block class="Custom\Theme\Block\Template" name="custom_head" template="html/head.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Thanks. Please tell me where to place this code?

Comment: i have added code in layout/default.xml.

Comment: top of file after <body> tag

Comment: Okay, I don't have "layout/default.xml" directory under my custom theme. What should I do?

Comment: first override default.xml file in your theme. please google it

Comment: okay, will do as advised. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107876/discussion-between-devidas-and-codeforgood).

Comment: I find it a bit difficult to override default.xml

Comment: May I know where exactly you placed this class "class="Custom\Theme\Block\Template"?

Comment: Are you placing all the related block class, template and layout files inside the app/code or app/design?

Comment: in app/design folder

Comment: Using your code I get the content output inside the Body, not Head in Magento 2.3.5. We also have default_head_blocks.xml, but removing it does not produce any difference: still outputs in body section.